# Nodejs: Date().toLocaleString() format changed between Node 9 and 10; affects Jest snapshots

Tags: node.js, date, jestjs

I had been using Node 9 and recently upgraded to Node 10.4.0.  I now notice that the format of Date().toLocaleString() has changed:

OLD: 2018-6-5 21:33:01
NEW: 6/5/2018, 9:33:01 PM

Anyone know why this changed between Node versions?  I tested on multiple platforms (Linux, Windows)

This has also broken the Jest snapshots as date strings in the snapshots have changed: "2017-9-3" vs "9/3/2017"

Is there anyway to control this format in our build / automated testing process?  I'm in a large group of developers and not everyone is running the same version of Node.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that happened to me too :-(

Comment: In "normal" JavaScript, we can pass a locale parameter, like `toLocaleString('en-GB')`. Try it here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tolocalestring

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21053
It seems to be an issue for more people. We just had an issue with spaces after the currency sign.

We also hardcode the locale string.